# Java how to split strings at a space, after a certain number of characters

Tags: java, string, split

(question was closed because to broad so i have tried to be more clear)

I found a many duplicate questions, but they were all in other programming languages.

I have a string and every 68 characters I want to break the string. But that will most likely cause the sentence to be broken in the middle of a word.

For example

> I am a love cats and dogs but not the flees they carry. Also i thin
>   k that cats are sometimes rude because they do not hug me when i wa
>   nt them too. Overall though cats and dogs are both great.

Instead I would like to break these strings at the closest space *before* character 68. Then I can present the string in a way where they do not break the words in the middle.

Ultimately this problem could be probably be solved by a for loop checking each char 68 and below one at a time to see if they are spaces. When it finds the space it could then be cut at that char. Alternatively I could add in the words one at a time until i pass 68 characters and not add that last word. A third option would be to substring the string at the 68th character and then substring the string a second time at the lastIndexOf the space character.

However, all my ideas seem very inefficient and i was wondering if there were any already created or built-in string methods that could do this?

Comment: Ok, what's the problem? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Basic plan: Split input into words.  Build a string by adding words (along with spaces where necessary), with the condition that if adding a new word (with the space) makes the string too long, start a new string.  You will need to decide how to handle a case where a single word is too long.

Comment: _"Hopefully this is very clear"_ -- it certainly is. The problem is that StackOverflow doesn't work this way. We don't take problem statements and write solutions for you.  ***You*** write the code and make an attempt, and then when you find something you don't understand you ask a ***specific*** question.  _"Here's a problem, I have no idea what to do?"_ is not an acceptable post here.

Comment: Also, you've stumbled on to one of the _oldest_ problems in computer text manipulation.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap  Another requirement before posting here is to have done basic research on the web to see if your problem has been already solved.

Comment: [`String#lastIndexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - thank you! That is a good idea, i will see if i can implement that to solve the problem!

Comment: @JimGarrison - I agree and understand your complaint, i have an idea of how i could proceed (i have shown in the edit) but i assumed that this type of problem had a more efficient solution which is what i was looking for. Furthermore it seems like a problem this "old" should be answered on a website like this.

Comment: @ajb, It's simpler to scan the given string keeping track of the last space character seen.  If and when you get to the 68th character, you'll know where to split it.

Comment: @jameslarge Yeah, there are a ton of ways to do it.  I wasn't sure which one is simplest to grasp for a newer programmer, though.

Comment: If you already had an idea of how to solve it but wanted to ask about efficiency, you should have made that clear right away.  Your question made it sound like you had no idea how to form a plan to solve it.

Comment: @ajb - True, sorry i was not clear that i had already considered a few ideas, i will remember to mention that next time i ask a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`WordUtils.wrap()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#wrap(java.lang.String,%20int)) method from Apache commons [[code]](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#line.88):

Code:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

class WrapTest {
    public static void main (String[] args)  {
        String str = "I am a love cats and dogs but not the flees they carry. Also i think that cats are sometimes rude because they do not hug me when i want them too. Overall though cats and dogs are both great.";
        str = WordUtils.wrap(str, 68);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I am a love cats and dogs but not the flees they carry. Also i think
that cats are sometimes rude because they do not hug me when i want
them too. Overall though cats and dogs are both great.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew there must have been a method already written to solve this type of problem!